# Checkbox with ng-model that reflect if another element is showed

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-model

I have an element checkbox, that I want to reset the value of ng-model when another element is not showed, example: set to false if another element is not showed in my view. ng-show only hide my checkbox, but not reflect in object of controller.

```
<select ng-model="item.myOption" convert-to-boolean>
  <option value="false" selected>Option false</option>
  <option value="true">Option true</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.myChecked" ng-show="item.myOption">
```

Comment: not quite understand what you want to do.. what is the "another element"? "ng-show only hide my checkbox"?

Comment: @CharlieNg (sorry about my English), I want to hide my checkbox if in my select option is false for example, but also set its value to false. Only is allow to checked if my option is true (I need to pass this parameter to the service). Did you understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write small function on ng-change of select field, in which you can set model value of checkbox to either true or false or null.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.item = {myOption: "true"}
    $scope.myCheckbox = true;
    $scope.changed = function() {
     if($scope.item.myOption == "false") {
        $scope.myCheckbox = false;
     } else {
        $scope.myCheckbox = true;
     }
    }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ekNxZImNIBisBCrfZsFS?p=preview

Similarly, you can change any dependent field's value (like finding age field value right after user selects his DOB using datepicker, etc). You can use switchcase either for large set of values instead of if else inside change function